# How to draw this out using a timer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, timer, drawing, draw

I am trying to get this snowflake design to be "drawn out" using a "timer" on javascript. In one of the examples, this is how a circle is drawn:

http://jsfiddle.net/avanhout13/9opengv7/1/

```
var t = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var R = c.width/2;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


function doDrawing() {
    t = 0;


    // Clear the Canvas
    ctx.clear();

    // Create a random color
    var timesRun = 0;
    var color =  '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

    // Initial x and y
    var x = R+R*Math.cos(0);
    var y = R+R*Math.sin(0);

    // Start the Drawing
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);

    //Use the timer to create drawing
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
    timesRun += 1;
    if(timesRun === 65){
        clearInterval(interval); }

    drawCircle();}, 20); 

}

function drawCircle()
{
  t += 0.1;
  x = Math.floor(R+R*Math.cos(t));
  y = Math.floor(R+R*Math.sin(t));

  ctx.lineTo(x,y);  
  ctx.stroke();
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clear = 
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clear || function (preserveTransform) {
    if (preserveTransform) {
      this.save();
      this.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    }

    this.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    if (preserveTransform) {
      this.restore();
    }           
};
```

This is the snowflake design. I want to do a similar drawing technique but cannot seem to figure out how to get it to actively be drawn when the "draw" button is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/avanhout13/g8xs9Ljf/

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('snowflake'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    maxLevel = 2,
    branches = 7;

 canvas.width = 1000;
 canvas.height = 1000;

 ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

 let angle = Math.PI * 2 + Math.random();

 for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    drawLine(0);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI * 2 / 6);
 }


 function drawLine(level) {
    if (level > maxLevel) return;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
     ctx.lineTo(200, 0);
     ctx.stroke();


  for (let i = 1; i < branches + 1; i++) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(200 * i / (branches + 1), 0);

    ctx.save();

    ctx.rotate(angle);
    drawLine(level + 1);

    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save();

    ctx.rotate(-angle);
    drawLine(level + 1);

    ctx.restore();

    ctx.restore();

  }
 }
```

Any idea of how to get this to draw? Thank you.

Comment: you need 2 sets of timer one which initially calls drawline and other inside for loop . if you want branches to be parallel drawn you can lose the first timer

Comment: So a timer under the first "for" loop, calling "drawline"? Or a loop under "drawline" then another under the second "for" loop?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your js code isn't loaded in **file** type, otherwise you can not use the function by input it's name in the html tag directly.

In JSFiddle, it could be change by the select label on the top left corner of your js window.

Hope this could be help.

```html
<html lane='en'>
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title> Snowflake Spirograph</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <button onclick="draw()">Start Drawing</button>
   <canvas id="snowflake" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
 </body>
 </html>
```

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('snowflake');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const maxLevel = 2;
const branches = 7;

ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

let angle = Math.PI * 2 + Math.random();

function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    drawLine(1);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI * 2 / 6);
  }
}


function drawLine(level) {
  if (level > maxLevel) return;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 0);
  ctx.stroke();

  for (let i = 1; i < branches + 1; i++) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(200 * i / (branches + 1), 0);

    ctx.save();

    ctx.rotate(angle);
    drawLine(level + 1);

    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save();

    ctx.rotate(-angle);
    drawLine(level + 1);

    ctx.restore();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great, it pops up with the button - but I'm trying to get it to actually draw, like with a "pen". Any ideas?